# URL by making another page as intermediate in HTML website

Tags: html, url

I am having an HTML site https://example.com. I have a page named example.html. I want to make my page URL https://example.com/exam/example.html. Where exam is another page.

How to do this in HTML website?

I am using:

```
<a href="example.html"></a>
```

but this is not like what i want. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done as HTML + CSS are both for client side, if you would have made a server then from server side you could have changed this using route.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you'd have to create a directory called exam and have a file called example.html in that directory in the place that serves the domain example.com. :-)

Comment: If you create this folder/directory mentioned above, you will also need to update your HTML `a` tag to include the new `exam` directory like so: `<a href="exam/example.html"></a>`